# IE 8 Focus a div after the tab key has been pushed without jQuery

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, focus

We have a simple datagrid that we are enabling navigation via a the tab key. (we move to the next cell) In IE 7 & 8 when we hit the tab key it causes the focus to move off the grid to the next element.

In other browsers we prevent focus moving to the next element on the page by calling focus() on the div that contains our grid. In IE this does not work, the focus moves on regardless.

What can we do (without jQuery) to keep the focus on the grid so we can hit the tab key repeatedly and move through the cells in our grid?

The same issue also exists when pushing the enter key.

Comment: You'll need to post a minimal example of how your focus code works at present. Until HTML5, only elements like form controls, images and links could get focus. Now anything can.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Oh wait, I don't see _any_ code - please, help us to help you...

Comment: @RobG if all the code is going to be is div.focus() I don't think a code sample will make any difference. Sometimes I wonder if the request for a code sample is just an excuse for not answering.

Comment: if that doesn't start a flame war i dunno what will :)

Comment: @AranMulholland - OK, I'll bite (once): The code is obviously more than just `div.focus()` because that has to be called _from_ somewhere. OP must be handling _some_ event(s), perhaps blur and/or focus events so _that_ is the code we want to see. What the OP _should_ do is handle the keydown event on the div and cancel it if tab or enter is pressed. (And yes, _some_ questions are clear without a code sample, but this is not one such question.)

Comment: @nnnnnn that's the answer I just gave too. :) (before i read your above comment mind you) Showing that you could have answered it without a code sample as well. Sometimes English is an adequate language to describe a question.

Comment: @AranMulholland - Ha! Yes, I see your answer went up nearly a minute before my comment, too, so obviously you didn't copy the idea from me - though I hadn't seen your answer at the time either. I completely agree that sometimes plain English is enough. The reason I originally commented with a request for code rather than posting the same answer as you was that I decided not to rely on a guess about what I thought the OP was probably doing, but kudos to you (and +1) for going ahead with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your event handler (onkeydown, keypress etc) when you have finished handling the tab key use this code :)

```
return false;
```

This prevents the default behaviour from occurring and should stop the navigation from proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the [tabindex](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) attribute on elements in the order you want them visited. No script required.

However older browsers may not support the HTML5 version, but likely those browsers wont support *focus* on the same elements either.

Comment: Thank you RobG, I will try your method :)